# React does not recognize the `isActive` prop on a DOM element - styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I have the following `svg` component where I am passing props.

```
import React from 'react';
export default (props) => (
  <svg {...props}>
    <path
      d="M11.5 16.45l6.364-6.364"
      fillRule="evenodd"
    />
  </svg>
);
```

I then have a `styled-component` that looks like this.

```
const Icon = styled(_Icon)`
  ${props =>
    props.isActive &&
    css`
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    `};
`;
```

I am seeing the following `react` error.

> Warning: React does not recognize the `isActive` prop on a DOM element.

Comment: Is there something specific about the name `isActive`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with styled-components and I ended up doing something like this:

```
<Icon isactive={isActive.toString()} />

${props =>
  props.isactive === 'true' &&
  css`
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  `};
}
```

Comment: thanks! is that a bit hacky, or you reckon this is the best approach to take? Not really any definitive solution here - https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/pull/2093

Comment: It's a bit hacky there is no proper documentation on how to do it...

Answer (score 5):

```js
const StyledIcon = styled(({ isActive, ...props }) => <Icon {...props} />)`
  ${props =>
    props.isActive &&
    css`
      transform: rotate(-180deg);
    `};
`
```

Is the much less hacky solution that also prevents the property from being unnecessarily rendered to the DOM

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and fixed the error by passing the props into a Styled Component instead of a normal html element. For you, you would change the svg element to something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
export default (props) => (
  <SvgStyledComp {...props}>
    <path d="M11.5 16.45l6.364-6.364" fillRule="evenodd"/>
  </SvgStyledComp>
);
const SvgStyledComp = styled.svg`
  ${props => props.isActive && css`
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  `};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transient-props](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#transient-props).

here is tsx example :

> `Button` is antd Button

```js
import { Button } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface IMyButtonProps {
    $switchShape: boolean;
    $myColor: string;
    $myBorderColor: string;
}

let MyButton = styled(Button).attrs<IMyButtonProps>((props) => {
   
    // console.log(props);
   
    let myShape = props.$switchShape ? 'circle' : 'round';

    return { type: 'primary', shape: myShape };

})<IMyButtonProps>`

    margin-left: 10px;

    ${{
        padding: '100px',
    }}

    ${(props) => {
        
        // You can get the result of Attrs
        // console.log(props);
        
        return `
            color:${props.$myColor}
        `;
    }};

    ${(props) => {
        // CSSProperties
        return {
            borderColor: props.$myBorderColor,
        };
    }};
`;
```

> `ghost` is antd Button attr

```js
<MyButton ghost={true} $switchShape $myBorderColor='black' $myColor='red'>
    click me
</MyButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to fix this error is change props name to '$ + props_name'

- Example:

  interface MenuItemProps extends TypographyProps {
  $isActive?: boolean;
  }