# Warning: React does not recognize the `isNarrow` prop on a DOM element - Material UI Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to style a material UI component, this is my code:

```
export const CardContentStyled = styled(CardContent)`
  width: ${props => (props.isNarrow ? 'calc(100% - 60px)' : 'calc(100% - 200px)')};
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 60px;
`;
```

and then from the component I import all as ui and use it like this:

```
<ui.CardContentStyled isNarrow={isNarrow}>
   whatever
</ui.CardContentStyled>
```

It works, but I'm getting this error:

***Warning: React does not recognize the `isNarrow` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `isnarrow` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.***

I tried everything I found on here, I thing the only thing that worked was this:

[React does not recognize the `isActive` prop on a DOM element - styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58447435/react-does-not-recognize-the-isactive-prop-on-a-dom-element-styled-component)

but it seems a bit hacky, maybe there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source of card content component you will understand it passes all other props to "div" as {...others}. isNarrow is a "non default" props of the div which causes the error.

If you can live with the error, fine.

If you do not want the error, it is really not harder than to simply customise create your own component than to use CardContent with styled.

CardContent [source](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/CardContent/CardContent.js)

```
export const styles = {
  /* Styles applied to the root element. */
  root: {
    padding: 16,
    '&:last-child': {
      paddingBottom: 24,
    },
  },
};

const CardContent = React.forwardRef(function CardContent(props, ref) {
   /* add isNarrow below and apply your own conditional style */
  const { classes, className, isNarrow, component: Component = 'div', ...other  } = props; 

  return <Component className={clsx(classes.root, className)} ref={ref} {...other} />;
});
```